# Нахождение минимального произведения двух элементов, полученных с интервалом не менее 6 минут

Tags: pascal

С4 Как решить подобную задачу? ЕГЭ 2014 информатика

Не думаю, что мой вопрос вытекает за рамки тематики этого сайта, но заранее прошу прощения.

Попалась такая задача, да такая, что подобных не было ни в одном сборнике, ни в демоверсии. Задание было в реальных кимах 2014 года.
Пишу по памяти, поэтому некоторые детали я опускаю.

С4.

Ученые снимают с аппарата "Тонегава" показания раз в минуту.
На вход подается N - число показаний снятых в этот период и сами показания
Ваша задача - написать программу, которая будет находить минимальное произведение двух элементов, полученных с интервалом не менее 6 минут.

Пример вводных данных:

11
20
12
11
4
5
9
10
24
43
20
7

Пример выходных данных:
28

Элементы на входе гарантированно вещественные. Количество элементов до 1000. Максимальное показание 10000.

Ограничение по памяти: 1 килобайт.

Ограничение по времени: при увеличении кол-ва элементов в К раз, время выполнения не должно увеличиться более чем в К раз.

Подскажите хотя бы идею решения. Если нужны какие-либо уточнения - спрашивайте.

Comment: Да. Так и есть. Но подразумевается, что программе сразу дадут все показания на вход.

Comment: на моей памяти на ХК было несколько задач из С4, в большей части спрашивавшие наврали в формулировке. "По памяти" - не катит. Ищите точную формулировку. Например, в том виде как у вас написано, возникает больше непонимания, чем понимания, по крайней мере у меня (после четырех прочтений).

Comment: Я буду очень рад, если я ошибся когда в панике читал эту задачу. Очень надеюсь, что КИМы сольют. Мои сокамерники говорят, что я все правильно написал.

Comment: @Влад Каменев а вы случайно не переврали формулировку? Если у вас элементов может быть тысяа, но при этом ограничение в 1 килобайт, то вряд ли можно говорить о вещественных числах - получается, что на одно число приходится по одному байту. А хранение вещественных чисел в одном байте..теоретически, наверное, возможно, но на практике так нигде не делают

Comment: Подозреваю, что 1Kb относится не к входным данным, а к использованию программой каких-нибудь дополнительных внутренних структур. Но и в этом случаве всё равно не до конца понятно.

Comment: 1 килобайт отводится на переменные, которые ты используешь в своей программе. Входные данные тут вовсе не причем. @DreamChild

Comment: @Влад Каменев ваши же слова ведь: 

>Плюс массив не вариант, т.к 1000 элементов вещественных это больше чем 1 килобайт памяти

а сейчас вы говорите про то, что входные данные ни при чем. Вы уж определитесь тогда - при чем они или ни при чем

Comment: Если лимит по памяти не распространяется на входные данные то что мешает решить проблему тупо полным перебором?
Тупо берёшь каждый элемент массива и умножаешь на каждый из семи последующих элементов каждый раз сравнивая результат с текущим минимумом, если он ниже то в текущий минимум записывается новое значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. заводим очередь (fifo, без проблем реализуется на коленке из массива) на интервал - 6 элементов, заполняем первыми 6-ю элементами из входа.
2. начиная с 7 элемента входа начинаем искать минимум произведения.

   - на каждой итерации корректируем значение минимального 1-го множителя. он равен минимуму из текущего минимума и первого элемента в очереди
   - проверяем произведение полученного минимума и элемента из массива входа (7-й, 8-й и т.д.), сохраняем минимальное произведение
   - выталкиваем первый элемент из очереди (мы его уже учли либо в минимуме, либо он больше, значит не повлияет на результат уже), и вталкиваем в очередь новый элемент (только что обработанный) из входа.

Поскольку элементы вещественные, то надо в п. 2.1 и далее учитывать не только минимальный элемент, но и максимальный чтобы учесть отрицательные множители.
Плюс проверки входа - количество, область значений и т.д.

ЗЫ [демо](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJLUf/) на javascript'е.

Comment: <зануда>Там первое число во входных данных - это количество элементов</зануда>

Comment: @Veikedo, это было "подскажите хотя бы идею решения."

Answer (score 3):

Идея - пожалуйста :) Оптимизация - возможна...

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned int
data[] = { 11, 20, 12, 11, 4, 5, 9, 10, 24, 43, 20, 7 };

#define DATA_LENGTH (sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]))
#define INTERVAL    6

int main()
{
    unsigned long min = ULONG_MAX;
    size_t i, j;

    for( i = 0; i < DATA_LENGTH-INTERVAL; i++ )
    {
        for( j = i+INTERVAL; j < DATA_LENGTH; j++ )
        {
            unsigned long m = data[i] * data[j];
            if( m < min ) min = m;
        }
    }
    return printf( "min = %lu\n", min ) == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Числа на входе вещественные. Плюс массив не вариант, т.к 1000 элементов вещественных это больше чем 1 килобайт памяти. + Это не линейная сложность. За такое решение "в лоб" получим только 2 из 4 баллов. Я бы и сам так написал, но я хочу 4 балла, а не 2

Comment: >Числа на входе вещественные

Какая разница?

>массив не вариант

А что вариант? Это просто пример, откуда берутся входные данные. Не думаю, что на это распространяется невнятное "ограничение по памяти".

Answer (score 3):

1. Заведите переменную, в которой будете хранить минимальное произведение. В начале оно равно произведению 1-го и 2-го элементов
2. Сделайте цикл, в котором будете проходить от первого элемента входной последовательности до последнего
3. Внутри этого цикла сделайте еще один цикл от элемента i+1 до элемента i+6, где i - индекс элемента из предыдущего цикла
4. Внутри вложенного цикла сравнивайте переменную из первого  шага (ту, в которой храните минимальное произведение) с произведением i-го и о-го элементов (где j - индекс элемента из вложенного цикла). Если текущее произведение меньше минимума, то обновляете минимум.

Собственно, всё. Не забудьте также, что для i >= N-6 (N - длина входной последовательности) во вложенном цикле нужно корректировать диапазон вложенного цикла во избежание выхода за границы последовательности

Comment: асимптотика нелинейна